# Extracting values from rasters with different size in R

Tags: raster, r

I have 10,000 raster files with different sizes. I need to extract values based on a list of points.

I have used the following using the raster pckg:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(data.table)

files <-list.files(path='/media/ambra/sea_levelss', pattern='*.grd', recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)

st <- stack(files)
#Testing one file only:
ncfile <- brick('L1.grd', varname = "z") 

pts= read.table("/Documents/ambra/sea_levelss/data/Ptos.xy",sep="\t",head=F)  
extractedData <- extract(ncfile, pts, method = "bilinear")

 #Then for the 10k in loop:

for(i in seq_along(files)) {
extractedData = extract(raster(files[i]), pts, method="bilinear") 
}
```

So far, the latter worked for one file, but not when I need to go through all 10k files. I tried with loop but I failed -no error but goes long and only stores 1 column.

Any ideas on how to create a fast solution to read these rasters?

And merging the 10k and merging those values to my pts files (that contains x,y coordinates).

I have checked for a solution to my problem. Similar problems are around but none has led me to my solution. E.g [Extracting values from raster stack and aggregating results using R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174790/r-extract-values-from-raster-stack-and-aggregate-results).

Comment: What went wrong with the loop?

Comment: @Spacedman, is more an error message related to the loop where I put the extract function. " Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"character", "data.frame"’

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code with the loop and the error message? I'm guessing but I suspect you are running something like `extract(filename,...)` rather than `extract(raster(filename),...)`.

Comment: @Spacedman, I edited what I did, not sure if the loop itself is wrong the way I did it.

Comment: If things seem to be taking forever then print out the loop variable inside the loop so you can check progress and maybe estimate how long "forever" really is. Or look at the `txtProgressBar` function for a way to show a progress bar.

Comment: That loop works for me, except it doesn't accumulate the results over all the rasters (it only leaves the extracted values for the last raster in `extractedData`). Try storing each extraction in a list element. `extractedData=list()` outside the loop and then `extractedData[[i]] = ...` inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Spacedman , with that suggestion (extractedData=list() works well!